# Mobile Slideshow Not Centering

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, slideshow

I have a responsive site with a slideshow. I have set the slideshow to be 100% the width of the browser window, and that is working fine. The problem is, the slideshow is shifted a bit to the right, almost as if there is padding to the left of the image. The result is the user having to scroll to the right to see the entire slideshow. I have tried playing around with the attributes of the div and the slideshow itself, but with no luck. Any help with this issue is appreciated. Here is my CSS and HTML code:

**CSS**

```
html
{
background-color:#000000;
}

body
{
margin:0auto;
padding:0;
width:100%;
}

#header
{
margin:0auto;
padding-top:0.5%;
text-align:center;
}

#logo
{
margin:0auto;
max-width:186px;
max-height:123px;
padding-top:1%;
padding-bottom:15%;
text-align:center;
}

#banner
{
width:100%;
}

#home_content
{
width:100%;
padding-top:0.25%;
}

#history_content
{
width:100%;
padding-top:0%;
}

#home_slideshow
{
padding-top:1%;
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
}

#home_slideshow
{
padding-top:1%;
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
}

hr
{
border-color:#1BB7F2;
width:100%;
padding:0%;
}

#home_footer
{
width:100%;
margin-top:60%;
}

#history_footer
{
width:100%;
margin-top:155%;
}


.crossfadeHome>figure
{
animation:imageAnimation24slinearinfinite0s;
backface-visibility:hidden;
color:transparent;
opacity:0;
position:absolute;
text-alin:center;
width:100%;
z-index:0;
margin:0auto;
}

.crossfadeHome>figure:nth-child(1)
{
background-image:url('../photos/img_1.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.crossfadeHome>figure:nth-child(2)
{
animation-delay:6s;
background-image:url('../photos/img_2.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.crossfadeHome>figure:nth-child(3)
{
animation-delay:12s;
background-image:url('../photos/img_3.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.crossfadeHome>figure:nth-child(4)
{
animation-delay:18s;
background-image:url('../photos/img_4.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

@keyframesimageAnimation
{
0%
{
animation-timing-function:ease-in;
opacity:0;
}
8%
{
animation-timing-function:ease-out;
opacity:1;
}
17%
{
opacity:1
}
25%
{
opacity:0
}
100%
{
opacity:0
}
}

.crossfadeHistory>figure
{
backface-visibility:hidden;
color:transparent;
opacity:0;
position:absolute;
text-alin:center;
width:100%;
z-index:0;
margin:0auto;
}

.crossfadeHistory>figure:nth-child(1)
{
background-image:url('../photos/history_1.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.crossfadeHistory>figure:nth-child(2)
{
animation-delay:7s;
background-image:url('../photos/history_2.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.crossfadeHistory>figure:nth-child(3)
{
animation-delay:14s;
background-image:url('../photos/history_3.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.crossfadeHistory>figure:nth-child(4)
{
animation-delay:21s;
background-image:url('../photos/history_4.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

@keyframesimageAnimation
{
0%
{
animation-timing-function:ease-in;
opacity:0;
}
8%
{
animation-timing-function:ease-out;
opacity:1;
}
17%
{
opacity:1
}
25%
{
opacity:0
}
100%
{
opacity:0
}
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPEhtml>

<html>

<head></head>

<body id="body">

<!--HeaderSection-->

<div id="logo">
<a href="index.html"target="_self"><img class="logo"src="graphics/logo.jpg"style="display:block;margin:0auto;width:100%;height:auto;max-width:225px;max-height:196px;vertical-align:top;"alt=""title=""></a>
</div>

<div id="header">
<p id="contact_info">
<a href="tel://555-555-5555"style="margin-right:1%;"><imgsrc="graphics/icon_phone.png"style="width:11px;height:15px;vertical-align:middle;"alt="PhoneIcon"title="Call Us!!">(518)459-9843</a>
</p>
<pid="contact_info">
<ahref="example.com"></a>
&nbsp
</p>
<p id="contact_info">
<img src="graphics/icon_clock.png"style="width:17px;height:17px;vertical-align:middle;"alt="ClockIcon"title="Our Hours">
</p>
</div>

<div id="banner">
<hr/>
<p id="page_home_header">
</p>
</div>

<div id="page_home_main">
<p id="home_content">
</p>
<p id="page_home_link">
<a href="pages/link.html"target="_self">link</a>
<br/>
<br/>
<a href="http://www.site.php"target="_blank">site</a>
</p>
</div>

<div id="home_slideshow"class="crossfadeHome">
<figure>
<img src="photos/img_1.jpg"style="width:100%;height:auto;"alt=""/>
</figure>
<figure>
<img src="photos/img_2.jpg"style="width:100%;height:auto;"alt=""/>
</figure>
<figure>
<img src="photos/img_3.jpg"style="width:100%;height:auto;"alt=""/>
</figure>
<figure>
<img src="photos/img_4.jpg"style="width:100%;height:auto;"alt=""/>
</figure>
</div>

<!--FooterSection-->
<footer id="home_footer">
<hr/>
<p id="footer_copyright"><ahref="example.net"target="_blank">&copy;<script>document.write(newDate().getFullYear())</script>mysite</a></p>
</footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle at jsfiddle.net

Comment: @user8385857 did you check my answer?

Comment: Hi. I was playing around with the fiddle, and am not sure if it has the desired output. Here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/suokx2ew/3/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you **check typos** in your code.

Change `margin:0auto;` to `margin:0 auto;` and `text-alin:center;` to `text-align:center;`.

If you want to know more about `margin`, [click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/margin).

To check errors in your `css` you can visit [CSSLint](http://csslint.net).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. The missing space in the margin was from a formatting mistake in my post, and not in my actual file. The text-align typo on the other hand, was an oversight. I fixed the align, but the slideshow is still pushed to the right.

Comment: Hi. I think we posted around the same time. Please see my comment. Is there something else you recommend that I try? Thank you.

Comment: I cannot see any of your slide show images. Please change your images path and re-produce what you have asked?

Comment: I used URLs to images I found online of the same size. I am not sure why the images are not showing in my Fiddle. They appear when testing locally.

Comment: The link you provided in the comment contains `src="graphics/icon_clock.png"` local path. You can send me updated fiddle. Make sure you update the question above and let me know since comments are not for discussion.

Comment: I am only concerned with the slideshow, so rest of the graphics are not live. The slideshow is contained within <div id="home_slideshow"class="crossfadeHome">. Sorry I am new to fiddle. I can send you the live URL for the site if it helps you to see the issue on a mobile device

Comment: Yes you can send me.